# How to create a geometry column for a sf object in R

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

My data looks like :

```
example <- tibble(geometry = "POINT (-3.8258 43.4109)")
```

I would like to transform the example from a tibble to a sf object
I have the following solution but I was wondering if there is a simpler way (because I will have polygons and lines also)

```
left.border <- "POINT ("
right.border <- ")"
example %>% 
  mutate(coord =str_match(geometry, paste(left.border, '(.+)', right.border, sep=''))[,2]) %>% 
  separate( coord, c("X","Y"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(X = str_sub(X, 2)) %>% 
  mutate(Y = str_sub(Y,1,nchar(Y)-2)) %>%
  mutate(X= as.numeric(X),Y= as.numeric(Y) ) %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("X","Y"))
```

Comment: Were you intending that this operation result in a durable change to the original object??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your geometries are in well known text format, you can use :

```
example = sf::st_as_sf(example, wkt = "geometry")
```

Comment: Yes the sf library. I'm editting my answer so it is clearer.

Comment: Definitely what I was looking for. Thank you !